# Pandas: groupby is not computing pct_change properly

Tags: python, pandas

My data is:

```
>>> prices = pandas.DataFrame(
{"StkCode":["StockA","StockA","StockA","StockA","StockA","StockB","StockB","StockB","StockB","StockB","StockC","StockC","StockC","StockC","StockC",], 
"Price":[1035.23, 1032.47, 1011.78, 1010.59, 1016.03, 1007.95, 1022.75, 1021.52, 1026.11, 1027.04, 1030.58, 1030.42, 1036.24, 1015.00, 1015.20]}
)
```

Which gives:

```
      Price StkCode
0   1035.23  StockA
1   1032.47  StockA
2   1011.78  StockA
3   1010.59  StockA
4   1016.03  StockA
5   1007.95  StockB
6   1022.75  StockB
7   1021.52  StockB
8   1026.11  StockB
9   1027.04  StockB
10  1030.58  StockC
11  1030.42  StockC
12  1036.24  StockC
13  1015.00  StockC
14  1015.20  StockC
```

Then, I call:

```
>>> prices["Return"] = prices.groupby("StkCode")["Price"].pct_change(1)
```

I expect:

```
      Price StkCode    Return
0   1035.23  StockA       NaN
1   1032.47  StockA -0.002666
2   1011.78  StockA -0.020039
3   1010.59  StockA -0.001176
4   1016.03  StockA  0.005383
5   1007.95  StockB       NaN
6   1022.75  StockB  0.014683
7   1021.52  StockB -0.001203
8   1026.11  StockB  0.004493
9   1027.04  StockB  0.000906
10  1030.58  StockC       NaN
11  1030.42  StockC -0.000155
12  1036.24  StockC  0.005648
13  1015.00  StockC -0.020497
14  1015.20  StockC  0.000197
```

But, I actually get:

```
    Price   StkCode Return
0   1035.23 StockA  NaN
1   1032.47 StockA  -0.002666
2   1011.78 StockA  -0.020039
3   1010.59 StockA  -0.001176
4   1016.03 StockA  0.005383
5   1007.95 StockB  -0.007953
6   1022.75 StockB  0.014683
7   1021.52 StockB  -0.001203
8   1026.11 StockB  0.004493
9   1027.04 StockB  0.000906
10  1030.58 StockC  0.003447
11  1030.42 StockC  -0.000155
12  1036.24 StockC  0.005648
13  1015.00 StockC  -0.020497
14  1015.20 StockC  0.000197
```

It looks like returns are being computed for the first instance of StockB and StockC.

I'm using Python 2.7.  Is there something wrong with my code that it's disregarding the groupby?

Thanks!

Comment: I get your expected output on pandas 0.24. Try upgrading?

Comment: That is bug for pct_change , fixed in 0.24

Comment: I just upgraded to Pandas 0.24.2 and get the expected results now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataFrame's loc method will apply those values correctly:

```
prices.loc[:, 'Return'] = prices.groupby("StkCode")["Price"].pct_change(1)

    Price   StkCode Return
0   1035.23 StockA  NaN
1   1032.47 StockA  -0.002666
2   1011.78 StockA  -0.020039
3   1010.59 StockA  -0.001176
4   1016.03 StockA  0.005383
5   1007.95 StockB  NaN
6   1022.75 StockB  0.014683
7   1021.52 StockB  -0.001203
8   1026.11 StockB  0.004493
9   1027.04 StockB  0.000906
10  1030.58 StockC  NaN
11  1030.42 StockC  -0.000155
12  1036.24 StockC  0.005648
13  1015.00 StockC  -0.020497
14  1015.20 StockC  0.000197
```